# How to store data requested by android volley to make some processing on data out of on response?

Tags: android, android-volley

I want to store data requested by android volley to make some processing on data outside the onResponse ,I tried shared preference but it not updated if i have several volley requests.

```
 this.context=context;

    //"https://apifootball.com/api/?action=get_H2H&firstTeam=Arsenal&secondTeam=Chelsea&APIkey=**********"

    String URL="https://apifootball.com/api/?action=get_H2H&firstTeam="+team1+"&secondTeam="+team2+"&APIkey=****************8";
    //"https://apifootball.com/api/?action=get_countries&APIkey=*********";
    RequestQueue rq= Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    JsonObjectRequest objreq= new JsonObjectRequest(

            Request.Method.GET,
            URL,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    String Scores="";

                    //    Log.e("result:",response.get(0).toString());
                    JSONObject obj;

                    //  obj=response.getJSONObject("firstTeam_VS_secondTeam");
                    try {

                        JSONArray obj2 =response.getJSONArray("firstTeam_VS_secondTeam");
                        Log.e("obj", obj2.getJSONObject(0).getString("match_hometeam_score"));
                        Scores=Scores+ obj2.getJSONObject(0).getString("match_hometeam_score")+"\n"+obj2.getJSONObject(0).getString("match_awayteam_score")+"\n"+obj2.getJSONObject(0).getString("match_date");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                    }
                    share(Scores);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener(){

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("rest response",error.toString());
                }
            }
    );
    rq.add(objreq);
    SharedPreferences m=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    final String resp=m.getString("Response","");
    Log.e("Res","x");
    return  resp;
```

Comment: Shared preferences should only be used for a very minute amount of data. How often are you updating or accessing the stored data? You could use SQLite?

Comment: still saved old request in sqllite